# What's wrong with this MongoDB find() query (not equals)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to find all documents with a certain ID that don't have a status of -1.

Why does this give a syntax error in pymongo?

```
machine = db2.machine.find(
        {
            "account_id": account_id,
            "status": { $ne: -1 }
        }
   )
```

Note:

1. account_id is a variable with the value `ObjectId("5397929402b8541ae8a32349")`
2. If I remove the `status` line, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, you need to wrap `$ne` into a string in Python.

So:

```
machine = db2.machine.find(
    {
        "account_id": account_id,
        "status": { "$ne": -1 }
    }
)
```

This is because in Python when you define a dictionary, you can't do

```
{key: "one"}
```

You need to do

```
{"key": "one"}
```

In the first case, "key" refers to a variable which doesn't exist. You could ammend the first case as follows:

```
>>> key = "name"
>>> {key: "one"}
{'name': 'one'}
```

An additional complication in your case was that you were trying to access a variable named `$ne` which is an invalid variable name.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark your answer as soon as it lets me. Just out of curiosity, is it because $ is a reserved character, so it needs to be put into a string?

Comment: Updated my answer so you could see what was going on